# How to create a ghost symbol? Why it cannot work on Texpad, but can work on Overleaf?

Tags: overleaf, texpad

How can I add the ghost symbol like this? I used package 'halloweenmath', but it can only work on Overleaf. The ghost symbol is not shown when I use Texpad. Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: In addition to `\usepackage{halloweenmath}`, what did you use to get the ghost symbol?  When it doesn't work in TeXpad, do you get an error?

Comment: Thanks. I also used \mathghost when I try to insert a ghost symbol. There is no error just blank.